# Textures and no textures at the same time in metal, with multiply blending

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I'm drawing 2 different vertex buffers in metal, one with a texture (ignoring vertex color data) and the other without a texture (drawing purely the vertex color data):

```
let commandBuffer = self.commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: rpd)

//render first buffer with texture
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self.rps)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer1, offset: 0, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)
commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(self.texture, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(self.samplerState, at: 0)
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: count1, instanceCount: 1)


//render second buffer without texture
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self.rps)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer2, offset: 0, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)
commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(nil, at: 0)
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: count2, instanceCount: 1)

commandEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.present(drawable)
commandBuffer.commit()
```

The shader looks like this:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct Vertex {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float4 color;
    float4 texCoord;
};

struct Uniforms {
    float4x4 modelMatrix;
};

vertex Vertex vertex_func(constant Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                          constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                          uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    float4x4 matrix = uniforms.modelMatrix;
    Vertex in = vertices[vid];
    Vertex out;
    out.position = matrix * float4(in.position);
    out.color = in.color;
    out.texCoord = in.texCoord;
    return out;
}

fragment float4 fragment_func(Vertex vert [[stage_in]],
                               texture2d<float>  tex2D     [[ texture(0) ]],
                               sampler           sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]]) {

    if (vert.color[0] == 0 && vert.color[1] == 0 && vert.color[2] == 0) {
        //texture color
        return tex2D.sample(sampler2D, float2(vert.texCoord[0],vert.texCoord[1]));
    }
    else {
        //color color
        return vert.color;
    }

}
```

Is this there a better way of doing this? Any vertex that i want to use the texture i'm setting to black, and the shader checks to see if the color is black, and if so then use the texture, otherwise use the color.

Also, is there a way to blend the colored polys and textured polys together using a multiply function if they overlap on the screen? It seems like MTLBlendOperation only has options for add/subtract/min/max, no multiply?

Comment: I am new to Metal and was having hard time how to use use more than one texture on a vertex array this question will help me to do it I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to have two different fragment functions, one that renders textured fragments and another one that deals with coloured vertices.

First you would need to create two different `MTLRenderPipelineState` at load time:

```
let desc = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()    

/* ...load all other settings in the descriptor... */

// Load the common vertex function.
desc.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertex_func")

// First create the one associated to the textured fragment function.
desc.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_func_textured")
let texturedRPS = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: desc)

// Then modify the descriptor to create the state associated with the untextured fragment function.
desc.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_func_untextured")
let untexturedRPS = try! device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: desc)
```

Then at render time, before encoding the draw commands of a textured object you set the textured state, and before encoding the draw commands of an untextured object you switch to the untextured one. Like this:

```
//render first buffer with texture
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(texturedRPS) // Set the textured state
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer1, offset: 0, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)
commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(self.texture, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(self.samplerState, at: 0)
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: count1, instanceCount: 1)

//render second buffer without texture
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(untexturedRPS) // Set the untextured state
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.vertexBuffer2, offset: 0, at: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.uniformBuffer, offset: 0, at: 1)
// No need to set the fragment texture as we don't need it in the fragment function.
// commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(nil, at: 0)
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: count2, instanceCount: 1)
```

No change is required for the vertex function. While you need to split the fragment function into two:

```
fragment float4 fragment_func_textured(Vertex vert [[stage_in]],
                                       texture2d<float>  tex2D     [[ texture(0) ]],
                                       sampler           sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]]) {
    //texture color
    return tex2D.sample(sampler2D, float2(vert.texCoord[0],vert.texCoord[1]));
}

fragment float4 fragment_func_untextured(Vertex vert [[stage_in]]) {
    //color color
    return vert.color;
}
```

You could even go ahead and have two different vertex functions that output two different vertex structures in order to save a few bytes. In fact the textured fragment function only needs the `texCoord` field and not the `color`, while the untextured function is the other way around.

**EDIT:** You can use this fragment function to use both the texture color and the vertex color:

```
fragment float4 fragment_func_blended(Vertex vert [[stage_in]],
                                      texture2d<float>  tex2D     [[ texture(0) ]],
                                      sampler           sampler2D [[ sampler(0) ]]) {
    // texture color
    float4 texture_sample = tex2D.sample(sampler2D, float2(vert.texCoord[0],vert.texCoord[1]));
    // vertex color
    float4 vertex_sample = vert.color;
    // Blend the two together
    float4 blended = texture_sample * vertex_sample;

    // Or use another blending operation.
    // float4 blended = mix(texture_sample, vertex_sample, mix_factor);
    // Where mix_factor is in the range 0.0 to 1.0.
    return blended;

}
```

Comment: That's so much neater, thanks :) Any way to get the multiply effect? If i could somehow do it inside the shader it would be easy - just multiply the tex color and the color color

Comment: Of course you can! Then just use another fragment function like this:

Comment: I'll just edit the previous answer to show the new fragment function.

Comment: ah but i mean blending the texture on one poly, with the color of a different poly that's behind it in the scene... maybe that's asking a bit much of metal actually. I think i've got a different way to get the effect i want now, by having 2 separate metalviews, and drawing the results of each of them with coregraphics and blending them there